# Why does "ls 1>&2 2> /dev/null" output something to my console?

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe

I am trying to understand piping, and get confused about the result of the command below.

```
% ls 1>&2 2> /dev/null

Applications    Users       cores       home        sbin        var
Library     Volumes     dev     opt     tmp
System      bin     etc     private     usr
```

I think

- 1> &2 redirects stdin to stderr stream
- 2 > /dev/null redirects stderr to a garbage place

Therefore, I think I should see no output from the command above, but the command does output some results. Why?

Comment: Should this be on https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com?  (Hmmm, or even is it already there....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `1>&2` redirects stdout to where stderr is set to **at that point**, and at that point you haven't redirected stderr yet. Then, later, you redirect stderr to `/dev/null`. So stdout outputs to stderr's default destination.

Reverse the order so you redirect stderr to `/dev/null`, then redirect stdout to where stderr is (now) pointing:

```sh
ls 2>/dev/null 1>&2
```